# Java - Имена объектов потока

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Имеется цикл, в котором запускается отдельный поток на каждый идентификатор товара `id_product` :

```
for(Int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  ThreadTest obj_Test = new ThreadTest();
  obj_Test.run(id_product);
}
```

Получается, что объект `obj_Test` будет каждый раз переопределяться, даже если ранее созданный поток еще не завершился.

Программа с подобной реализацией отрабатывает верно и ошибок не появляется, интересует насколько верно такая реализация. Как я считал имя объекта класса `ThreadTest` должно быть уникальным, иначе могут возникнуть проблемы с переопределением объектов, которые еще не завершили свою работу.

Comment: Здесь нет имён. И нет ожидания выполнения.

Comment: это просто ссылки на объект класса, на который можно ссылаться сколько угодно раз, и поток будет создаваться каждый раз новый, верно?

Comment: Да, всё верно :)

Comment: @Алексей верно, чуть забегая вперед - треды сами по себе являются GC roots, поэтому то, от чего зависит и выполнение, из памяти никуда не пропадет до непосредственно заврешения треда. То, что в локальной области видимости остается только последний объект, на размещение этих объектов в памяти (в данном случае) не влияет. ну, конечно, с той оговоркой, что с этим объектом создается новый тред, а не .run выполняется последовательно.

Comment: @Etki @Qwerty Спасибо! Объясните еще в чем различие такого решения, где этот код будет выполняться опять же в цикле : `new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            obj.method1();
        }
    }).start();`  В данном случае потоки выполняются не все, хотя есть и те что отработали верно

Comment: Обратите внимание, что в вашем коде, хоть вы и создаете объекты класса ThreadTest (они, я так понимаю, наследники от `java.lang.Thread`) нет многопоточного выполнения. Для того чтобы задача выполнилась в отдельном потоке надо вызывать метод `start()`. Чтобы в этом убедиться сделайте внутри `run()` случайную задержку с помощью, например `Thread.sleep` и выведите после задержки что-нибудь в консоль.

Comment: @Alexandr Верно, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В указанном цикле в ссылочную переменную `obj_Test` записывается ссылка, на созданный в *куче* объект класса `ThreadTest()`. При каждой новой итерации цикла ссылка в переменной `obj_Test` будет обновляться и ссылаться на новый объект в *куче*.

Данное решение не позволит обратиться в случае необходимости, к созданным в цикле объектам класса `ThreadTest()` (кроме последнего). Но, с другой стороны, если обращаться к созданным в цикле объектам не нужно, то это сэкономит небольшое количество ресурсов JVM, т.к. переменная `obj_Test` будет хранить только одну ссылку на последний в итерации цикла объект.

Answer (score 0):

Имена потоков будут разные. Будет браться из toString созданного треда. По поводу задачи - если количество итераций цикла должно быть больше, то лучше использовать fixed thread pool.